# does git repo accumulate size when there is heavy branch which is deleted without merging back to master?

Tags: git, github

i'm trying to find the efficient way to temporarily add huge data files to git repo without having to make the history grow and make the overall repo very bulky. I need this as part of the automated deployment that I'm trying to develop.

My solution, which I'm trying to validate is,

- on the database server:

  - generate the data files for the deployment,
  - create a new branch,
  - commit and push the data files to the new branch,
- on the deployment server:

  - git clone the new branch and download data files, and
  - remove the branch without merging it back to master.

What i'm trying to validate here is, if I follow this approach, would the repo be relatively small, as I'm not retaining the branch, and never merging it back to master? I don't want the repo to accumulate the large files history over time and make it very slow to use the repo. I'm trying to reproduce the scenario by myself to verify, but because of the latency issues, i'm not able to effectively validate the actual size of the repo. Any thoughts and suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: At any point in this process, are you pushing commits to the repository?  Not just commiting things in the repository, but actually publishing them in the repository?

Comment: yes, i'm. after I commit. let me try to update the question. thanks for asking,

Answer (score 0):

The repo's size would change due to the fact that you're adding blobs at some point in the repo's history.  It doesn't matter if you've merged it into master or not; the fact that these files are *reachable* is what counts.

If you want to avoid adding large files into your repository as a significant burden, look into [git-lfs](https://git-lfs.github.com/) to store these larger binaries, which will completely *bypass* the problem by storing the binaries somewhere else, referenced by a commit.

Comment: i have two challenges with git-lfs. 1) I dont know yet if git-lfs is supported for Github enterprise. 2) I'm assuming the same problem would still exist with git-lfs as it accumulates the history. or doesn't it?

Comment: @srini:  Given that GitHub originally *developed* git-lfs, I would be stunned if they *didn't* support it in Enterprise.  Also, the history would only point to a single file and not the entire binary, keeping the binaries out of your repo but still well-tracked.  You would do well to peruse their documentation.

Comment: looks like the git-lfs is supported for Github Enterprise. need to give a try. however, i'm not sure about my second concern from my comment above.

Comment: thanks @Makoto, I'll try it out and will let you know how it goes.